# Call stored procedure from PL/SQL Job

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, syntax-error

In sqlplus I created the procedure, whitch fill my table GeneratedData with int values...

```
create procedure fillGeneratedData (x in int) as
begin
for i in 1..x loop
insert into GeneratedData values (i);
end loop;
end;
/
```

I want to create job, whitch call this procedure, but it throws errors and dont call the procedure...

```
BEGIN
sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job( 
job_name => 'job1',
job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
job_action => 'begin exec fillGeneratedData(50000); end;',
repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=2',
start_date => systimestamp at time zone 'Europe/Belgrade',
auto_drop => FALSE,
enabled => TRUE);
END;
```

sqlplus says PL/SQL procedure successfully completed, but when i look to alert log, it throw error:

Tue Apr 01 00:50:45 2014
Errors in file c:\app\adbsuser\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_7516.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 74677
ORA-06550: line 1, column 734:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "" to continue.
Errors in file c:\app\adbsuser\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_7516.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 74679
ORA-06550: line 1, column 734:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FILLGENERATEDDATA" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "FILLGENERATEDDATA" to continue.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, you PL/SQL block is not valid.  If you tried to run just this

```
begin 
  exec fillGeneratedData(50000); 
end;
```

you'd get an error.  You don't use `exec` in a PL/SQL block-- that's a SQL*Plus command.  Your PL/SQL block would just be

```
begin 
  fillGeneratedData(50000); 
end;
```

Comment: thanks, but now it throws this error:
Tue Apr 01 01:07:00 2014
Errors in file c:\app\adbsuser\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_j000_8944.trc:
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 74678
ORA-06550: line 1, column 734:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FILLGENERATEDDATA" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "FILLGENERATEDDATA" to continue.

Comment: @weto - First things first, can you run the anonymous PL/SQL block on its own successfully?

Comment: Now I find, that this error was error from running previuous job and its work.. :) Thnaks...